# Polar equation for a k-leaf rose: is it possible to define an inner radius?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Is it possible to define a polar equation for a k-leaf rose with an inner radius for a k-leaf rose (as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIgml.png))? I'm familiar with the general equation for a k-leaf rose 
$$r = \cos(k*\theta)$$
and the corresponding Cartesian equations 
$$x = \cos(k*\theta) * \cos(\theta)$$
and 
$$y = \cos(k*\theta) * \sin(\theta)$$
However, I've been unable to use these to come up with an equation that produces a rose with a hollow center. I'm very curious to know if it's possible. Thanks in advance, any insights will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try $r=\cos(k\theta)+c$ where $c>1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:  cosine goes to zero, so the inner radius is not there, and cosine goes negative so adding a bit doesn't do what you want.  If you square the cosine you can add a bit.  This doesn't look like your figure, but it does have an inner radius

[image]
If you increase the denominator it looks like this

[image]
You can play with the parameters a bit

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! It looks like increasing the additive constant to a number greater than 1 yields a [smooth inner radius](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+cos%5E2%283*theta%2F5%29+%2B+3).

Comment: @IanSpeers:  I had fun with it.  Just adding a larger constant makes the ratio of outer/inner too small to my eye.  If you make the additive constant greater than $1$ you can [remove the square from the cosine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3Dcos+%285*theta%2F7%29%2B2)  See how you like it.  This goes fully to David Quinn's suggestion

Comment: Beautiful! The removal of the square will help to cut down on compute time. Now I just need to convert this bad-boy into Cartesian. Hopefully my calc isn't too rusty :). Thanks again!